# Unable to get HTML element from Iframe VBA

Tags: html, vba

I am facing issues while trying to get elements from Iframe. I suppose that the main problem is that frame is located at another source. Could you please share with me ways of working with such webpages? thanks in advance
`Set element = objIE.document.getElementById("frame-container") Set element = element.getElementsByTagName("app-fulfillment-uvkh6f") Set element = element.getElementById("find-a-transaction")`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu6zr.png)

Answer (score 0):

The IFrame is probably loaded by Javascript as the page is dynamic, i.e. first the javascripts are loaded, then those javascripts are loading the content.

To solve this (if you're ok with using a DLL and rewrite your code), you can run Microsoft's Edge browser (a Chrome-based browser) with VBA. With that you can do almost anything you want. Note however, that access to the DOM is performed by javascript, not by an object like Dim IE As New InternetExplorer. Look at the VBA sample and you'll get the grasp.

https://github.com/peakpeak-github/libEdge

Sidenote: Samples for C# and C++ are also included.